# Server 2008 R2 TS brokering

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, hp, rdp

I am using Server 2008 R2 as a terminal services broker for 5 Server 2008 R2 terminal servers. I am using the HP 5325 thin client to connect to the TS's. I have the thin-clients set to auto-login, which works fine while connecting to the brokering server but when the session is passed to a terminal server the user has to enter in the login credentials which include the domain\UN and password, which defeats the purpose of auto-login which it must do. Is there way around this secondary login?

Thanks in advance for your help

Answer (score 0):

I believe I've seen this before, some clients had the issue when some did not. I narrowed it down to it being an issue mainly on XP computers that were not using RDC 6.1, which support Single Sign On http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=7208

Comment: Thanks, but these Thin Clients use HP's version of Linux operating system. We have other Thin Clients that are running XP and dont have an issue.

Comment: I'm pretty sure the issue is that the client that you are using does not support the Single Sign On function.

Comment: Linux clients tend to be pretty problematic unless they are using a recent version of freerdp.